# Android WebView для личного кабинета сайта

Tags: java, android

Использую `WebView` для отображения страницы личного кабинета на сайте. Обработка всех операций выполняется на стороне сервера(т.е. загружается просто мобильная версия сайта). Ранее с данным компонентом не работал, по этому возникает ряд вопросов:

1. Какие могут быть "подводные камни" в реализации данной задачи?
2. Есть ли какие-то механизмы защиты или кеширования данных? Нужно ли это вообще?
3. Если к примеру, пользователь залогинился, то это состояние будет сохраняться на стороне клиента(т.е. мобильного приложения) или на стороне сервера?
4. Какие еще есть, на первый взгляд, очевидные вещи, которые необходимо реализовать?

Как мне кажется, не может же быть все так просто: создать `WebView`, назначить ему страницу по умолчанию и все

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если надо будет чистить куки смотрите в сторону:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        Log.d(C.TAG, "Using ClearCookies code for API >=" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1));
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
        CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
    } else
    {
        Log.d(C.TAG, "Using ClearCookies code for API <" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1));
        CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr=CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
        cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
        CookieManager cookieManager=CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
        cookieSyncMngr.sync();
    }
```

Далее нужно будет перехватить клики по ссылкам чтобы они открывались в том же окне:

```
new WebViewClient() {  
  @Override  
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  
  {  
    view.loadUrl(url); //this is controversial - see comments and other answers
    return true;  
  }  
});
```